# How to get rid of annoying popups in Pycharm that make it hard to code fluidly?

Tags: python, pycharm

How can I disable all of these popups? With them there I have to click to make them go away just so I can type on the next line. It's extremely annoying.[image: !enter image description here]

I tried disable code completion but it did not get rid of these popups.

Comment: I think your pycharm might be broken, that doesn't look normal.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Running on macOS 13.3.1 M2

Comment: FWIW, I removed the previous installation of PyCharm community edition which I had installed via JetBrains Toolbox, and re-installed by downloading directly from JetBrains. This fixed the problem for me.